# "autocmd FileType" doesn't work the same way in Mac and Linux

Tags: linux, mac, vim, vi

Here is a small vimrc snippet that I was trying to use on my Mac

```
function SetCommonDefaults()
  " Set line numbers
  set nu
endfunction

autocmd FileType cpp call SetCommonDefaults()
```

What I expect this to do is, to display line numbers when I open up files of type cpp for editing. While this works fine in Linux, it doesn't work for me in Mac. I am not using MacVim, but the standard vim binary that comes pre-loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `filetype on` somewhere in your `~/.vimrc`?

Anyway, filetype specific settings should be placed in a separate file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim
```

without `autocmd`s. So, basically, only line 3 of your example.